# Butterknife bound buttons OnclickListener not working

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-viewholder, butterknife

I have set an onclick listener within a viewholder in a fragment in my android app.

```
package store.snapcart.snapshopper.ui.fragment.main;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import me.yoctopus.cac.util.LogUtil;
import store.snapcart.snapshopper.R;

public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {
    private String TAG = LogUtil.makeTag(DashboardFragment.class);
    private OnInteractionListener listener;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    public DashboardFragment() {
    }

    public static DashboardFragment newInstance() {
        DashboardFragment fragment = new DashboardFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //we have to initialize the views inside the viewholder
        //to use the this listener, we have to implement it in the dashboard acticity
        holder = new ViewHolder(view, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnInteractionListener) {
            listener = (OnInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }

    public interface OnInteractionListener {
        void onShiftClicked(Button button);

        void onTestClicked(Button button);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.shopper_image)
        ImageView shopperImage;
        @BindView(R.id.shopper_name)
        TextView shopperName;
        @BindView(R.id.shift)
        Button shift;
        @BindView(R.id.dashboard_list)
        ListView dashboardList;
        @BindView(R.id.test)
        Button test;

        ViewHolder(View view, final OnInteractionListener listener) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

            LogUtil.e("ViewHolder", "setting up viewholder");
            //we'll set the onclick listener here
            test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LogUtil.e("Holder", "on click test");
                    listener.onTestClicked((Button) v);
                }
            });
            shift.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LogUtil.e("Holder", "on click shift");
                    listener.onShiftClicked((Button) v);
                }
            });

            LogUtil.e("ViewHolder", "set up viewholder");
        }
    }
}
```

The log statements with ViewHolder are executed but if I click the buttons(any of them), the log staments within the onclick listener doesn't work.

Incase this is necessary, my build tools are 25.0.3, am running this code on test device  running android 7.1.1
Kindly assist me solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: test and shift are buttons already initialized

Comment: Where are they initialized? How did you do that before you bound `Butterknife`?

Comment: I initialized everything in butterknife, it's in a viewholder

Comment: Sure, but if the button clicks are not "triggering", then you are using the wrong view references

Comment: Here is the full code:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1n9VisiDZuGlyJJIxl1hrBDfTdF0aZtMyo7oOTpNfOQs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, but please **[edit]** the post

Comment: I am using the id(s) of the right buttons

Comment: I'm sure you are, but again, it would be beneficial to see that part of the code

Comment: i have just edited the snippet

Comment: Have you tried moving the OnClickListeners inside the `onViewCreated(...)` method?

Comment: Nope, but how will initialize the viewholder out of that method